# get data by id then storing it on a state

Tags: arrays, react-native, axios, setstate

i was trying to get a row of data by id from existing array inside a state, is this the right way to do it? cause it keeps on doing the thing on loop, i was trying to do a similar thing but calling it from the api, but it had similar error where i got 429 http error, means i keep calling the api nonstop.

I was trying to get a row and then view the details on another component.

My function:

```
const getAnime = (id) => {
    let filteredAnime = data.filter((item) => item.mal_id === id) //data is a state
    console.log(filteredAnime)
    setAnime(filteredAnime) //this is setting a state
  };
```

The button:

```
<Button title="Detail" onPress={getAnime(item.mal_id)} />
```

The error:

> [Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops.] PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too
> large

I haven't thought of how to view details component, was thinking of using modal navigator, a suggestion beside the answer might be nice, i'm still new to react native.

Edit:
Found a better way to pass the value without the need to use state, i don't know if it's actually better, but **if it works, don't touch it**
I'm just passing the renderItem from flatlist as param from this method, and then calling them on the expected component.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and change the way you are passing your function to the onPress. Talking from a ReactJs perspective, it's supposed to be:

<Button title="Detail" onClick={() => getAnime(item.mal_id)} />

but I guess you can change the onClick to onPress to suit your use case. Most important thing is to wrap the function in a callback to avoid multiple calls. I hope it works for you.

Comment: As a matter of fact i already tries that but forgot that i have another screen with similar button function, but still uses the one i posted. 
I guess i'm too hasty at this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to give callback to the function

```
<Button title="Detail" onPress={()=>getAnime(item.mal_id)} />
```

Comment: As a matter of fact i already tries that but forgot that i have another screen with similar button function, but still uses the one i posted. 
I guess i'm too hasty at this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you are calling the function in the button

```
<Button title="Detail" onPress={()=>getAnime(item.mal_id)} />
```

That will make the work :)

Comment: As a matter of fact i already tries that but forgot that i have another screen with similar button function, but still uses the one i posted. 
I guess i'm too hasty at this, thanks!